# I have a working Datatables/ajax table for php 5.6.6 it gives error on php 7 and does not populate

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

Currently I have a simple Employee Phone Book page that is being populated from a MySQL table -> employee . I am using Datatables to format and bring data in through a simple AJAX/JQuery/JSON Call and return, I am also using Datatables, Bootstrap, and  to format the page output.

From their Site I have the various parameters set up in my Document.ready area-.

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#employee').dataTable( {
 "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
 "aProcessing": true,
 "aServerSide": true,
  "ajax": "assets/server-response-emp.php",

     dom: 'Blfrtip',buttons: [

            {
                extend: 'print',
                customize: function ( win ) {
                    $(win.document.body)
                        .css( 'font-size', '7pt')
                        .prepend(
                            '<img src="" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />'
                        );
                     $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                        .addClass( 'compact' )
                        .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                }
            },
           {    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'Letter',
                title: 'Emplopee Directory'
            }

            ]
    } );
    } );

    </script>
```

Also From their examples, I am using the basic php

```
<?php
    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine, 2012 - Chris Wright
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array('emp_no', 'last_name', 'first_name',  'email', 'phone');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "last_name";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "employee";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "*******";
    $gaSql['password']   = "*******";
    $gaSql['db']         = "*******";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /*
     * Local functions
     */
    function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
    {
        header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
        die( $sErrorMessage );
    }


    /*
     * MySQL connection
     */
    if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
    }

    if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
    }


    /*
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /*
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    /*
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    */

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

When switching to PHP 7 it errors out

This set-up works fine when I switch back to PHP 5.6.16

I am running all on Server 2008 R2 IIS

Appreciate any help. I would like to be able to upgrade Live server to 7

Comment: The original MySQL extension was depreciated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7, so your `mysql_*` functions are probably throwing errors. See [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: suppress the warnings by inserting `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` as the very first line in your PHP script.

Comment: I stopped using the datatables PHP a long time ago. There's really no reason for it assuming you're passing a well-formed JSON object into AJAX. I would focus on using your PHP to create this object and pass that into the `data` parameter. Create a new build of datatables JS and include all the plugins you want including filtering, etc. You can take all of that out of your PHP, which should remove your errors. Have the PHP just create the data object. Create your build here: http://datatables.net/download/index

Comment: Thanks All for the Help.
The error, is really just a return of No object. So I think that the approach from jonmrich will be the best approach. I am really just using datatables as a nice formatter. I can change to hard CSS for that.
As for the MySQL extension .. ah wel Duh! :) i might have just not looked at on the new toolset.